# UWP New Application view

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am building a new app, which in desktop mode, relies heavily on structure with many windows.

In WPF, this is so incredible simple to manage. But in UWP i am almost loosing my mind with adapting to different ui threads due to very much mvvm. I am now making new constructors and handle propertychanged so many places which i do not need in single ui thread mode.

Is there some magic way of making new applicationview on the apps current ui thread?

I hope there are some gurus here

Comment: Right, that's what you get for hastily reading questions. Yes, of course, each `CoreWindow` runs in its own thread, with its own input handling and message dispatching. It's the hierarchy of `UIElement`s inside the view that run on the same thread. Sorry.

Comment: I see no reason to be separate ui thread. Wpf and winforms handles all this just fine on single UI thread. I am well aware of this from other uwp projects, i was just wondering if there exists a way to go around this without a layer between the different threads

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the thread of the new Window.

Maybe you could use something like an EventAggregator ([here's an example from Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/EventAggregator.cs)) to communicate between the Windows? The EventAggregator could help to hide some of the details of communicating between the different threads.

One idea is that each Window creates its own EventAggregator but they have a shared set of handlers/subscribers. With each subscriber you store correct CoreDispatcher:

```
    public class MyEventAggregator
    {
        private static List<Tuple<CoreDispatcher, object>> subscribers = new List<Tuple<CoreDispatcher, object>>();

        public void Subscribe<TMessage>(ISubscriber<TMessage> subscriber)
        {
            subscribers.Add(new Tuple<CoreDispatcher,object>(Window.Current.Dispatcher, subscriber));
        }
```

So Window1 creates its own EventAggregator and subscribes as a listener:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, MainPage.ISubscriber<Message>
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var eventAggregator = new MyEventAggregator();
        eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

And Window2 creates its own EventAggregator. Window2 is created using the [CoreApplication.CreateNewView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views):

```
public sealed partial class Secondary : Page
{
    public MainPage.MyEventAggregator EventAggregator;

    public Secondary()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.EventAggregator = new MainPage.MyEventAggregator();
    }
```

Keep in mind, both the EventAggregators in Window1 and Window2 has a shared set of subscribers.

Then when you want to send a message from Window2 to Window1, you just call Publish. This code is from button click in Window2:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.EventAggregator.Publish(new Message("hello from second view"));
    }
```

And the EventAggregator makes sure that the Window1 receives the message in its own UI thread. So Window1 can just update the UI:

```
    public void Handle(Message message)
    {
        this.Message.Text = message.Text;
    }
```

Here's a really to-the-point implementation of the Publish-method:

```
        public void Publish<TMessage>(TMessage message)
        {
            var messageType = GetEventType(message);

            foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
            {
                var handler = subscriber.Item2;

                if (messageType.IsInstanceOfType(handler))
                {
                    var dispatcher = subscriber.Item1;
                    dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        ((ISubscriber<TMessage>)handler).HandleMessage(message);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        private static Type GetEventType<T>(T args)
        {
            return typeof(ISubscriber<>).MakeGenericType(args.GetType());
        }
```

In reality, one should make sure to use WeakReferences or some other functionality to make sure that GC can clean up things.

The [full example of EventAggregator](https://gist.github.com/mikoskinen/935608835f27e6d8ecbe63483709ddf1) is available through Gist.